# Laravel Spark 9.0 undefined currency label

Tags: laravel, laravel-cashier

I have upgraded Laravel to 6.0, Laravel Spark to 9.0 and Cashier to 10.0

In the Spark Subscription settings I am seeing **undefined** as the currency instead of $.

I tried adding CASHIER_CURRENCY=usd to .env but no difference.

Here is what I see:

[image]

Anyone else seen this?

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be a dependancy issue in package.json.

```
    "vue": "2.6.10",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10"
```

These have to be the same version.

Answer (score 0):

I have upgraded Laravel to 6.0, Laravel Spark to 9.0 and Cashier to 10.0

In the Spark Subscription settings, I am seeing undefined as the currency instead of £.

I tried adding CASHIER_CURRENCY=eur to .env but no difference.